# How do I update state of parent class where Ive defined contexAPI , when I submit a form in child component?

Tags: reactjs, undefined, this, react-context

How do I update state of the class where parent contex api is defined ,  when I submit form from a child component  ??

```
import React, {createContext,Component} from 'react'
import http from './services/httpService'
import {MyApiUrl} from './services/httpService'


export const GlobalState = createContext()

export class DataProvider extends Component{

    state={
        jobs:[],
        loadstate:false,
    }

    async populateCategories() {
      
            const {data:jobs}=await http.get(MyApiUrl+'/api/jobs')
            this.setState({jobs})
        
        
console.log('hellow world')
return

}

      

    async componentDidMount(){
        await this.populateCategories()
       
    }


     logPokemon = this.populateCategories.bind(this); 

    // async  setUser() {
       
    //      await this.populateCategories()
    //   }
    

   

render(){
    const {jobs}=this.state;

    const{logPokemon}=this
    const{children}=this.props
    return (
        <GlobalState.Provider value={{logPokemon,jobs}}>
            {children}
        </GlobalState.Provider>
    )
}

  
}
```

now from another child component , when a form is submitted I did this , And I got a Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

```
static contextType = GlobalState

    const {logPokemon} = this.context;
    logPokemon()
```

Comment: can u format snippet via prettier or smth and provide code, where u render `DataProvider` and its children?

Answer (score 1):

Only Call Hooks from React Functions. Class components don't support hooks - [Hooks-FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both)

> You can’t use Hooks inside of a class component, but you can
> definitely mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single
> tree. Whether a component is a class or a function that uses Hooks is
> an implementation detail of that component. In the longer term, we
> expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components.

You can not use `createContext` hooks or any other react `hooks` in the class base component. Hooks are only used in the functional components. Learn more about [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Comment: https://www.taniarascia.com/using-context-api-in-react/  , please check this article , i guess u can , I am able to print jobs in child component which means it did work , but when i call the logpokemon fn () it says Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component ,

Comment: Hey it's working with this code itself ,

Comment: Hey it's working with this code itself , should I continue ..... Or is it not advisable .

Comment: But it's not recommended way. React officially not allowed to do that